# TypeError: "TypeError: function name is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (/:2:54)"

Tags: javascript, html, function, typeerror

I'm trying to build a really simple survey on Javascript but I keep getting this error "TypeError: startSurvey is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (/:2:54)" I would really appreciate if anybody can help me solve this error or provide any further feedback and suggestions.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div class="surveysection">
    <button onclick="startSurvey()" id="startSurvey">Start Survey</button>
    <div id="questions"></div> 
</div>

<script>
```

Here's my script file:

```
var ourQuestions = [
  {
    question:'While naturally occurring wildfires can benefit ecosystems, unnatural blazes started by uncaring and negligent humans can do great harm and cause many deaths. What percentage of wildfires do you think are started by humans?',
    answers: {
      a: '10-15%',
      b: '85-90%',
      c: '45-50%',
      d: '25-30%'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'b'
  },
  {
    question: 'If you have lit a campfire before, how did you extinguish it?',
    answers: {
      a: 'I did not extinguish it and waited for it to die on its own',
      b: 'I extinguished the campfire with a bucket of water and made sure it was fully extinguished.',
      c: 'I have never lit a campfire before.',
      d: 'uhhh'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'b'
  },
  {
    question: 'What are the two most common reasons that forest fires start?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Lightning and human negligence',
      b: 'Spontaneous combustion and erosion',
      c: 'Animals igniting flames and overcrowded bushlands',
      d: 'uhhh'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'a'
  },
  {
    question: 'What time of the year do most forest fires occur?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Summer',
      b: 'Spring',
      c: 'Fall',
      d: 'Winter'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'a'
  },
  {
    question: 'How fast do you think forest fires spread?',
    answers: {
      a: '10.8 km/h',
      b: '6.4 km/h',
      c: '22.2 km/h',
      d: '3.2 km/h'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'a'
  },
  {
    question: 'What do forest fires need in order to burn?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Water',
      b: 'High humidity',
      c: 'Fuel',
      d: 'Clear weather'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'c'
  },
  {
    question: 'What is one of the main toxic gases present in forest fire smoke?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Osmium tetroxide',
      b: 'Disulfur decafluoride',
      c: 'Tungsten hexafluoride ',
      d: 'carbon monoxide'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'd'
  },
  {
    question: 'What natural disasters could be caused as a consequence of a destructive forest fire?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Erosion, flash flooding and landslides',
      b: 'Tornadoes',
      c: 'Snow',
      d: 'Tsunami and earthquakes'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'a'
  },
  {
    question: 'What major factor determines a forest fire’s behaviour?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Amount of water vapour in air',
      b: 'Density of Forests',
      c: 'Wind',
      d: 'Hours of sunlight'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'c'
  }
];

function startSurvey(){
    
    var i;
    var j;
    var k;
    for(i=0; i<ourQuestions.length; i++){
        document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML +='<form id="question">Q'+(i+1)+': '+ ourQuestions[i].question;
        
        for(j=0; j<ourQuestions[i].answers.length; j++){
            document.forms[i].innerHTML += '</div><div class="answer"><input name="q1" value="'+ ourQuestions[i].answers[j] +'" id="value4" type="checkbox" />' + ourQuestions[i].answers[j] + '<br/>';
         }
     document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML +='</form><br/><br/>';
    }
    
    document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML += '<button onclick="solveQuiz()">Solve Quiz</button>';
    
}

function solveSurvey(){
  var x;
  var txt = ' ';
  var i = 0;
  var correct = 0; 
  for(i = 0; i < document.forms.length;i++) { 
    x = document.forms[i]; 
    for(j = 0; j<x.length; j++){
      if(x[j].checked) { 
        correctAnswer = ourQuestions[i].correctAnswer;
        if(x[j].value == ourQuestions[i].answers[correctAnswer]){
          correct += 1;
        }
      }
   }
 }
 document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML += 'Correct answers: '+ correct;
} 

document.forms[i].innerHTML += '</div><div class="answer"><input name="q1" value="'+ ourQuestions[i].answers[j] +'" id="value4" type="radio" />' + ourQuestions[i].answers[j] + '<br/>';
```

Comment: Didn't someone already answer this? Name the function and the ID of the element two different things.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work it said "ReferenceError: Survey is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick" @berkobienb

Comment: Change `onclick` to `onClick`

Comment: ok now it says "ReferenceError: startSurvey is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick" @berkobienb

Comment: Place your script inside the body tag

Comment: @berkobienb im sorry how do i do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-t

Comment: Look at the Answer with the 2100 upvote. You need to ensure that your whole DOM is loaded before trying to access the button click.

Comment: wait so correct me if I'm wrong, but do I just put everything that is in my script file in HTML?

Comment: Just link the JS like this. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_script_src . Are you doing that much?

Comment: oh so link it by using this "<script src="demo_script_src.js">"? @berkobienb

Comment: Okay. Are your JavaScript and HTML in the same document or are they in two separate documents?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224061/discussion-between-berkobienb-and-28space-junkiee).

Comment: two seperate files so javascript is in a file called "script.js" and HTML is in "index.html"

Comment: sorry I mixed it up, I did not mean to I just fixed it!

Comment: @berkobienb i marked it correct, let me know if its fixed

Comment: Its fixed thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fiddle fixing your issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/bradberkobien/x4hjy8m2/3/

Change your function to be `startSurvey()` instead of just `start()`.

Also, move your `document.forms[i].innerHTML +=` line up into the for loop in your `solveSurvey()` function.

Also, make sure your script is linked correctly (this was ultimately the problem in **repl.it**)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your id and function are the same name, below I changed the function name to  `start();`. - This alone will probably fix your problem.

Additionally it looks like i is not defined here:

```
document.forms[i].innerHTML += '</div><div class="answer"><input name="q1" value="'+ ourQuestions[i].answers[j] +'" id="value4" type="radio" />' + ourQuestions[i].answers[j] + '<br/>';
```

You might want to fix that.

```js
var ourQuestions = [
  {
    question:'While naturally occurring wildfires can benefit ecosystems, unnatural blazes started by uncaring and negligent humans can do great harm and cause many deaths. What percentage of wildfires do you think are started by humans?',
    answers: {
      a: '10-15%',
      b: '85-90%',
      c: '45-50%',
      d: '25-30%'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'b'
  },
  {
    question: 'If you have lit a campfire before, how did you extinguish it?',
    answers: {
      a: 'I did not extinguish it and waited for it to die on its own',
      b: 'I extinguished the campfire with a bucket of water and made sure it was fully extinguished.',
      c: 'I have never lit a campfire before.',
      d: 'uhhh'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'b'
  },
  {
    question: 'What are the two most common reasons that forest fires start?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Lightning and human negligence',
      b: 'Spontaneous combustion and erosion',
      c: 'Animals igniting flames and overcrowded bushlands',
      d: 'uhhh'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'a'
  },
  {
    question: 'What time of the year do most forest fires occur?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Summer',
      b: 'Spring',
      c: 'Fall',
      d: 'Winter'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'a'
  },
  {
    question: 'How fast do you think forest fires spread?',
    answers: {
      a: '10.8 km/h',
      b: '6.4 km/h',
      c: '22.2 km/h',
      d: '3.2 km/h'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'a'
  },
  {
    question: 'What do forest fires need in order to burn?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Water',
      b: 'High humidity',
      c: 'Fuel',
      d: 'Clear weather'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'c'
  },
  {
    question: 'What is one of the main toxic gases present in forest fire smoke?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Osmium tetroxide',
      b: 'Disulfur decafluoride',
      c: 'Tungsten hexafluoride ',
      d: 'carbon monoxide'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'd'
  },
  {
    question: 'What natural disasters could be caused as a consequence of a destructive forest fire?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Erosion, flash flooding and landslides',
      b: 'Tornadoes',
      c: 'Snow',
      d: 'Tsunami and earthquakes'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'a'
  },
  {
    question: 'What major factor determines a forest fire’s behaviour?',
    answers: {
      a: 'Amount of water vapour in air',
      b: 'Density of Forests',
      c: 'Wind',
      d: 'Hours of sunlight'
    },
    correctAnswer: 'c'
  }
];

function start(){
    
    var i;
    var j;
    var k;
    for(i=0; i<ourQuestions.length; i++){
        document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML +='<form id="question">Q'+(i+1)+': '+ ourQuestions[i].question;
        
        for(j=0; j<ourQuestions[i].answers.length; j++){
            document.forms[i].innerHTML += '</div><div class="answer"><input name="q1" value="'+ ourQuestions[i].answers[j] +'" id="value4" type="checkbox" />' + ourQuestions[i].answers[j] + '<br/>';
         }
     document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML +='</form><br/><br/>';
    }
    
    document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML += '<button onclick="solveQuiz()">Solve Quiz</button>';
    
}

function solveSurvey(){
  var x;
  var txt = ' ';
  var i = 0;
  var correct = 0; 
  for(i = 0; i < document.forms.length;i++) { 
    x = document.forms[i]; 
    for(j = 0; j<x.length; j++){
      if(x[j].checked) { 
        correctAnswer = ourQuestions[i].correctAnswer;
        if(x[j].value == ourQuestions[i].answers[correctAnswer]){
          correct += 1;
        }
      }
   }
 }
 document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML += 'Correct answers: '+ correct;
} 

document.forms[i].innerHTML += '</div><div class="answer"><input name="q1" value="'+ ourQuestions[i].answers[j] +'" id="value4" type="radio" />' + ourQuestions[i].answers[j] + '<br/>';
```

```html
<div class="surveysection">
    <button onclick="start()" id="startSurvey">Start Survey</button>
    <div id="questions"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: hi it says "ReferenceError: start is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick" also how would I be able to define 'i', sorry for asking too many questions I'm really new to this

Comment: sorry i forgot to tag you